# Calculating Clustering Coefficient

Tags: excel, cluster-analysis

I have my data in the form such as:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Author_ID   Year    CoAuthor_Count  High    Medium  Low     Deviant Paper_Count
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
677         2005    1               1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    3
677         2007    3               0.66    0.00    0.33    0.00    1
677         2009    1               0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    1
677         2011    5               0.60    0.00    0.40    0.00    1
677         2012    2               1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    1
677         2013    5               0.60    0.40    0.00    0.00    2
1359        2005    11              0.00    0.00    0.81    0.18    11
1359        2006    27              0.00    0.14    0.70    0.14    20
1359        2007    29              0.00    0.06    0.62    0.31    12
1359        2008    29              0.00    0.10    0.55    0.34    13
1359        2009    28              0.00    0.32    0.53    0.14    18
1359        2010    22              0.04    0.18    0.59    0.18    14  
...  
...  
...
```

whereas `High`, `Medium`, `Low` and `Deviant` columns representing the similarity value between `Author` and `CoAuthor`. In the same form I also have the data regarding `Author` and `Venue` similarities and counts.

I have used `Microsoft Clustering` to cluster these data, it was successful as assigning each row a cluster label.

But the issue is I want to calculate the clustering coefficients of these data, whereas the data should be in graphical form (nodes, edges) to calculate the cluster coefficients.

How can clustering coefficient of these data be calculated?

Comment: `I have used Microsoft Clustering to cluster these data`: Could you expand on that ? What is this ? Any source ?

Comment: @kebs This is a data mining Add-ins for excel by Microsoft i.e.
[Microsoft Clustering Algorithm] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174879.aspx  
[Data Mining Client for Excel] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282385.aspx


  [1]:

Comment: What is the "cluster component coefficient"? I have never heard of it, and **google gives 0 results**. How are we going to answer when you ask for something that does not exist? (Also, don't expect us to write code for you - start coding, ask with code!)

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Cluster Component Coefficient and Clustering Coefficient are two same concepts

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I need idea for implementing clustering coefficient for my data (as above) whereas all examples I have found are for networked data

Comment: What did you try so far? Also note that the clustering coefficient is *only* for networked data *by design*.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I have tried only simple microsoft clustering, So is there any hint to convert given data into networked data ?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse The columns in the given may be skipped but the target is Author_ID, Year, Paper_Counts and Similarity values i.e. **High**, **Medium**, **Low** and **Deviant**. Can these values be merged into single for simplification forwarding towards networked data

Comment: This is tabular data. It just is not networked data. Why do you insist on using a measure meant for graphs?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I have to do multi-typed object clustering i.e. Authors, Venues, Papers, Research_Areas similarity between them. So an algorithm for multi-typed clustering i.e. EvoNetClus uses graph networked data, so is the reason

Comment: But this **is not** graph networked data!

Comment: @Anony-Mousse But there might be some way to sort out! Vertices are **Author_ID**, **CoAuthor_ID**, **Year**, **AC_Similarity**, **AV_Similarity** and **Paper_Count** and the values of attributes define weighted edges between vertices, so the networked data, I just need a tool, tip or easy way to convert this data into networked data

Comment: In the data you showed above, there is no `CoAuthor_ID` that could be used. Anyway, don't use Excel for such tasks.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I have skipped showing, but it is there in the original data, so nothing can be done to convert it in networked form?

Comment: It already is in graph form then, no need to cnvert. You only need a tool that understands graphs...

Answer (score 0):

MS Clustering does not give you any formula to calculate the (local) clustering coefficient of an author.

Rather the Microsoft Clustering gives you (according to the documentation) two algorithms, k-means Clustering and EM Clustering (which is related to k-Means, it is [more general](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76866/clustering-with-k-means-and-em-how-are-they-related)). Broadly speaking, these are methods to structure the dataset as a whole.

The "Clustering Coefficient" you are probably looking for is more a property of the relationship network of an author.

It is a case of unfortunate naming. There is one name/attribute for different concepts:

- "Clustering algorithms", the unsupervised machine-learning methods
- "Clustering coefficient", the measure from graph theory

The [local clustering coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient) can be calculated as follows

```
for each author 
  create a list of  coauthor-ids of this author (this column is missing in your table)
  for all coauthor-ids from that list, 
     count/sum the the unique mutual coauthorship-pairs between them, but not with the author himself 

  Divide this by the number of coauthors per author (you already have this one, CoAuthor_Count)
```

See the illustration on the right of the wikipedia page linked above.

I haven't looked for Excel plugins or VBA molules or Add-Ins that do this.

Comment: @knb--you are right for calculating local clustering coefficient in this way but what for other types of attribute associated with the column `Author_ID` e.g. `Venue`, if number of linked attributes with `Authors` are more than `1`, then how to compute local clustering coefficient?